# Rules based engine for determining service price. Suggestions?

Tags: architecture, software-design, rule-engine

I would like to implement an engine in which end users create services and for those services, they  define rules that applies to specific range of dates but other rules might prevail in case the rule applies and has a higher priority.

For example, let's say I create a service, and I create a rule that defines the price for this service with "from monday to sunday price is 1$.". Then I create a second rule which says "day 24 of december price is 2$", and I set this rule as more important than the first I mentioned.
In this case, if the range of dates I am calculating includes the 24 of december, the engine must state that the cost is 2$ for that day.

What I am trying to find is the best way to implement this engine, and how to come up with something that might calculate the total price that would cost a service for a given range of dates in an efficient way.

I have some ideas but probably the ones more obvious, so I am trying to see if there is some way I had not thought of. This is more a generic software architecture question, but for if helps, I will implement it in Python/Django in a relational database.

Thanks,

Comment: It is never a good idea to implement your own business rules engine. The topic is MUCH MORE complex than you might think. Any open source or commercial  rules engine can easily handle your use case(s). You'll save a lot of time, money and nerve cells by getting one of those engines.

Comment: I might consider this option as well. Do you recommend/know any open source or commercial engine? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it's against the policy of StackOverflow to recommend particular products in here. But you'll plenty of choices just by googling for "Python business rules engine" or whatever platform you use. Good luck!